# Knockout - write different observed values for input and for style

Tags: knockout.js

An observable integer, that stores a value which is used for css variables, like `width`, or `height`. In order to be correctly applied in css, these variables need an additional unit, like `px` or `mm`. However, in my viewmodel I want to store pure integers and want to be able to change it in a input field.

What I need now, is a way to tell knockout that whenever this value is inserted into a `style`- binding, it has to be augmented with the respective unit string (`px`).

https://jsfiddle.net/nfyosayr/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nfyosayr/8/) is a working fiddle. Simply update the backing observable (`mywidth`) as such:

```
<input type="number" data-bind="textInput : mywidth" />
```

And the computed should be read-only:

```
this.myfullwidth = ko.computed(function() {
  return self.mywidth() + 'px';
});
```

And finally, apply the resulting value to the div:

```
<div id="my-div" style='background-color:red' data-bind="style : { width : myfullwidth }">
  this is my div
</div>
```

**Alternative solution:**

You can take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nfyosayr/7/) fiddle. You can also bind to your backing observable and add the `px` suffix in your markup. Make sure, however, that in this case, you need to apply a set of parentheses `()` in your HTML:

```
data-bind="style : { width : mywidth() + 'px' }"
```

Comment: This looks good, bud I actually wanted to avoid having to write a new `ko.computed` for every css attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it with a custom binding:

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.style_extended = {
                init: function(element,valueAccessor,allBindingsAccessor,box) {

                    var obj = valueAccessor();
                    for(let index in obj) {
                        if (index != 'unit') {
                            element.style[index] = obj[index]()+obj['unit'];
                        }
                    }
                },
                update: function(element,valueAccessor,allBindingsAccessor,box) {

                    var obj = valueAccessor();
                    for(let index in obj) {
                        if (index != 'unit') {
                            element.style[index] = obj[index]()+obj['unit'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

<div style='background-color:red' data-bind="style_extended : { width : mywidth }">
  this is my div
</div>
```